# How to replicate/mirror ActiveStorage blobs from production S3 bucket to development Local?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I have a production system using an Amazon S3 bucket for storing ActiveStorage blobs (Rails 6.0.3).

For development, I use the Local service because I don't want to inadvertently mess with the production data.

What is the best way to replicate/mirror/sync the production bucket locally so I can use it just a as scratch for development and testing?

I have tried replicating the production database locally and copying the bucket directly to the Local service directory but ActiveStorage doesn't see the blobs with the right keys. (Not sure why?)

I have also seen some examples of the Mirror service being used between cloud services or from Local to cloud services, but not from cloud services to Local.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is organized in subdirectories

```
$ tree storage
storage
├── ZD # first 2 char
│   └── ou # third and fourth car
│       └── ZDouA9nEzJjWAx71Cmb3WVeY
```

while S3 stores file in flat format (no under sub-directories). The above file will be store as a direct file under the bucket

```
ZDouA9nEzJjWAx71Cmb3WVeY
```

I don't know it applies to Rails (and which version). But I had succeeded in transferring development storage files to S3 using the above concept (Spree 4 - which uses rails framework 6).